# Perl, loop through array of hashes and print a specific hash element based on criteria

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

I have a bigger multidimensional hash which consist of hashes and array within it, I'm able to get the array of hashes out of that which is only useful of the entire larger hash, now I'm trying to print a specific element or values of a key.

**Original Hash**

```
{
      "grade1": {
        "sections": {
          "groups": "group-a"
        }
      },
      "grade2": {
        "sections": {
          "groups": "group-b"
        }
      },
      "grade3": {
        "departments": [
          {
            "allowedsubjects": "\ngeneral\nmath\nphysics\nchemistry",
            "name": "class1",
            "multiple": false,
            "description": "",
            "required": "optional"
          },
          {
            "allowedsubjects": "\ngeneral\nbiology\nphysics\nchemistry",
            "name": "class2",
            "multiple": false,
            "description": "",
            "required": "optional"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**My Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cpanel::JSON::XS;
use strict;
use v5.16.3;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_text ='{ "grade1": { "sections": { "groups": "group-a" } }, "grade2": { "sections": { "groups": "group-b" } }, "grade3": { "departments": [ { "allowedsubjects": "\ngeneral\nmath\nphysics\nchemistry", "name": "class2", "multiple": false, "description": "", "required": "optional" }, { "allowedsubjects": "\ngeneral\nbiology\nphysics\nchemistry", "name": "class1", "multiple": false, "description": "", "required": "optional" } ] } }';

my $json_obj = decode_json($json_text);

#print Dumper $json_obj;
my %school = %{$json_obj};
## Half working
    my @AoH = @{$school{"grade3"}{"departments"}};
    my @lines;
    for my $href ( @AoH ) {
        for my $key ( keys %$href ) {
          push @lines, $href->{$key};
         }
    }
print @lines;
```

**Output**

```
0optionalclass2
general
math
physics
chemistryoptionalclass1
general
biology
physics
chemistry0
```

How can I print just the values of allowedsubjects based on class1 or class2 as criteria.

**Expected Out put if class1 is selected**

```
general
math
physics
chemistry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by avoiding needless copies of hashes and arrays. We're also going to use better variable names than `AoH`, `href` and `key`.

```perl
my $school = decode_json($json);
my $depts = $school->{grade3}{departments};
```

Now we want the departments that have the value of `$dept_name` for name. `grep` is a good tool for filtering.

```perl
my $dept_name = 'class1';
my @matching_depts = grep { $_->{name} eq $dept_name } @$depts;
```

Then, it's just a question of iterating over the matching departments, and printing the desired values.

```perl
for my $dept (@matching_depts) {
   say $dept->{allowedsubjects};
}
```

Except not quite. That prints

```
                 <-- Blank line
general
biology
physics
chemistry
```

Fix:

```perl
for my $dept (@matching_depts) {
   say substr($dept->{allowedsubjects}, 1);
}
```

Alternative fix:

```perl
for my $dept (@matching_depts) {
   my @subjects = grep { $_ ne "" } split /\n/, $dept->{allowedsubjects};
   for my $subject (@subjects) {
      say $subject;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify quite a bit in your code. It boils down to this loop.

```perl
for my $department ( @{ $school->{grade3}{departments} } ) {
    if ($department->{name} eq 'class1') {
        print $department->{allowedsubjects};
    }
}
```

I've dropped your `@lines` as there is no need to store the output for this example. I've also removed `@AoH`, as we can access that directly. I've renamed `$href` to `$department`, which is more descriptive.

It then boils down to looking at the specific `name` key inside each department, comparing with the class you wanted, and then printing the `allowedsubjects` directly.